# How can I rotate an image based on object position?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

First off, sorry for the length of the post.

I'm working on a project to classify plants based on an image of the leaf. In order to reduce the variance of the data I need to rotate the image so the stem would be horizontally aligned at the bottom of the Image (at 270 degrees).

**Where I am at so far...**

What I have done so far is to create a thresholded image and from there find contours and draw an ellipse around the object (in many cases it fails to involve the whole object so the stem is left out...), after that, I create 4 regions (with the edges of the ellipse) and try to calculate the minimum value region, this is due to the assumption that at any of this points the stem must be found and thus it will be the less populated region (mostly because it will be surrounded by 0's), this is obviously not working as I would like to.

After that I calculate the angle to rotate in two different ways, the first one involves the `atan2` function, this only requires the point I want to move from (the centre of mass of the least populated region) and where `x=image width / 2` and `y = height`. This method works in some cases, but in most cases, I don't get the desired angle, sometimes a negative angle is required and it yields a positive one, ending up with the stem at the top. In some other cases, it just fails in an awful manner.

My second approach is an attempt to calculate the angle based on 3 points: centre of the image, centre of mass of the least populated region and 270º point. Then using an `arccos` function, and translating its result to degrees.

Both approaches are failing for me.

**Questions**

- Do you think this is a proper approach or I'm just making things more complicated than I should?
- How can I find the stem of the leaf (this is not optional, it must be the stem)? because my idea is not working so well...
- How can I determine the angle in a robust way? because of the same reason in the second question...

Here are some samples and the results I'm getting (the binary mask). The rectangles denote the regions I'm comparing, the red line across the ellipse is the major axis of the ellipse, the pink circle is the centre of mass inside the minimum region, the red circle denotes the 270º reference point (for the angle), and the white dot represents the centre of the image.

[image: Original image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My current Solution**

```py
    def brightness_distortion(I, mu, sigma):
        return np.sum(I*mu/sigma**2, axis=-1) / np.sum((mu/sigma)**2, axis=-1)
    
    
    def chromacity_distortion(I, mu, sigma):
        alpha = brightness_distortion(I, mu, sigma)[...,None]
        return np.sqrt(np.sum(((I - alpha * mu)/sigma)**2, axis=-1))
    
    def bwareafilt ( image ):
        image = image.astype(np.uint8)
        nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=4)
        sizes = stats[:, -1]
    
        max_label = 1
        max_size = sizes[1]
        for i in range(2, nb_components):
            if sizes[i] > max_size:
                max_label = i
                max_size = sizes[i]
    
        img2 = np.zeros(output.shape)
        img2[output == max_label] = 255
    
        return img2
    
    def get_thresholded_rotated(im_path):
        
        #read image
        img = cv2.imread(im_path)
        
        img = cv2.resize(img, (600, 800), interpolation = Image.BILINEAR)
        
        sat = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,1]
        val = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,2]
        sat = cv2.medianBlur(sat, 11)
        val = cv2.medianBlur(val, 11)
        
        #create threshold
        thresh_S = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(sat , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);
        thresh_V = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(val , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);
        
        #mean, std
        mean_S, stdev_S = cv2.meanStdDev(img, mask = 255 - thresh_S)
        mean_S = mean_S.ravel().flatten()
        stdev_S = stdev_S.ravel()
        
        #chromacity
        chrom_S = chromacity_distortion(img, mean_S, stdev_S)
        chrom255_S = cv2.normalize(chrom_S, chrom_S, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)[:,:,None]
        
        mean_V, stdev_V = cv2.meanStdDev(img, mask = 255 - thresh_V)
        mean_V = mean_V.ravel().flatten()
        stdev_V = stdev_V.ravel()
        chrom_V = chromacity_distortion(img, mean_V, stdev_V)
        chrom255_V = cv2.normalize(chrom_V, chrom_V, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)[:,:,None]
        
        #create different thresholds
        thresh2_S = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(chrom255_S , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);
        thresh2_V = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(chrom255_V , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);
            
    
        #thresholded image
        thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh2_S, cv2.bitwise_not(thresh2_V))
        
        #find countours and keep max
        contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
        big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
            
        # fit ellipse to leaf contours
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(big_contour)
        (xc,yc), (d1,d2), angle = ellipse
        
        print('thresh shape: ', thresh.shape)
        #print(xc,yc,d1,d2,angle)
        
        rmajor = max(d1,d2)/2
        
        rminor = min(d1,d2)/2
        
        origi_angle = angle
        
        if angle > 90:
            angle = angle - 90
        else:
            angle = angle + 90
            
        #calc major axis line
        xtop = xc + math.cos(math.radians(angle))*rmajor
        ytop = yc + math.sin(math.radians(angle))*rmajor
        xbot = xc + math.cos(math.radians(angle+180))*rmajor
        ybot = yc + math.sin(math.radians(angle+180))*rmajor
        
        #calc minor axis line
        xtop_m = xc + math.cos(math.radians(origi_angle))*rminor
        ytop_m = yc + math.sin(math.radians(origi_angle))*rminor
        xbot_m = xc + math.cos(math.radians(origi_angle+180))*rminor
        ybot_m = yc + math.sin(math.radians(origi_angle+180))*rminor
        
        #determine which region is up and which is down
        if max(xtop, xbot) == xtop :
            x_tij = xtop
            y_tij = ytop
            
            x_b_tij = xbot
            y_b_tij = ybot
        else:
            x_tij = xbot
            y_tij = ybot
            
            x_b_tij = xtop
            y_b_tij = ytop
            
        
        if max(xtop_m, xbot_m) == xtop_m :
            x_tij_m = xtop_m
            y_tij_m = ytop_m
            
            x_b_tij_m = xbot_m
            y_b_tij_m = ybot_m
        else:
            x_tij_m = xbot_m
            y_tij_m = ybot_m
            
            x_b_tij_m = xtop_m
            y_b_tij_m = ytop_m
            
            
        print('-----')
        print(x_tij, y_tij)
        

        rect_size = 100
        
        """
        calculate regions of edges of major axis of ellipse
        this is done by creating a squared region of rect_size x rect_size, being the edge the center of the square
        """
        x_min_tij = int(0 if x_tij - rect_size < 0 else x_tij - rect_size)
        x_max_tij = int(thresh.shape[1]-1 if x_tij + rect_size > thresh.shape[1] else x_tij + rect_size)
        
        y_min_tij = int(0 if y_tij - rect_size < 0 else y_tij - rect_size)
        y_max_tij = int(thresh.shape[0] - 1 if y_tij + rect_size > thresh.shape[0] else y_tij + rect_size)
      
        
        x_b_min_tij = int(0 if x_b_tij - rect_size < 0 else x_b_tij - rect_size)
        x_b_max_tij = int(thresh.shape[1] - 1 if x_b_tij + rect_size > thresh.shape[1] else x_b_tij + rect_size)
        
        y_b_min_tij = int(0 if y_b_tij - rect_size < 0 else y_b_tij - rect_size)
        y_b_max_tij = int(thresh.shape[0] - 1 if y_b_tij + rect_size > thresh.shape[0] else y_b_tij + rect_size)
        
    
        sum_red_region =   np.sum(thresh[y_min_tij:y_max_tij, x_min_tij:x_max_tij])
    
        sum_yellow_region =   np.sum(thresh[y_b_min_tij:y_b_max_tij, x_b_min_tij:x_b_max_tij])
        
        
        """
        calculate regions of edges of minor axis of ellipse
        this is done by creating a squared region of rect_size x rect_size, being the edge the center of the square
        """
        x_min_tij_m = int(0 if x_tij_m - rect_size < 0 else x_tij_m - rect_size)
        x_max_tij_m = int(thresh.shape[1]-1 if x_tij_m + rect_size > thresh.shape[1] else x_tij_m + rect_size)
        
        y_min_tij_m = int(0 if y_tij_m - rect_size < 0 else y_tij_m - rect_size)
        y_max_tij_m = int(thresh.shape[0] - 1 if y_tij_m + rect_size > thresh.shape[0] else y_tij_m + rect_size)
      
        
        x_b_min_tij_m = int(0 if x_b_tij_m - rect_size < 0 else x_b_tij_m - rect_size)
        x_b_max_tij_m = int(thresh.shape[1] - 1 if x_b_tij_m + rect_size > thresh.shape[1] else x_b_tij_m + rect_size)
        
        y_b_min_tij_m = int(0 if y_b_tij_m - rect_size < 0 else y_b_tij_m - rect_size)
        y_b_max_tij_m = int(thresh.shape[0] - 1 if y_b_tij_m + rect_size > thresh.shape[0] else y_b_tij_m + rect_size)
        
        #value of the regions, the names of the variables are related to the color of the rectangles drawn at the end of the function
        sum_red_region_m =   np.sum(thresh[y_min_tij_m:y_max_tij_m, x_min_tij_m:x_max_tij_m])
    
        sum_yellow_region_m =   np.sum(thresh[y_b_min_tij_m:y_b_max_tij_m, x_b_min_tij_m:x_b_max_tij_m])
        
     
        #print(sum_red_region, sum_yellow_region, sum_red_region_m, sum_yellow_region_m)
        
        
        min_arg = np.argmin(np.array([sum_red_region, sum_yellow_region, sum_red_region_m, sum_yellow_region_m]))
        
        print('min: ', min_arg)
           
        
        if min_arg == 1: #sum_yellow_region < sum_red_region :
            
            
            left_quartile = x_b_tij < thresh.shape[0] /2 
            upper_quartile = y_b_tij < thresh.shape[1] /2
    
            center_x = x_b_min_tij + ((x_b_max_tij - x_b_min_tij) / 2)
            center_y = y_b_min_tij + (y_b_max_tij - y_b_min_tij / 2)
            
    
            center_x = x_b_min_tij + np.argmax(thresh[y_b_min_tij:y_b_max_tij, x_b_min_tij:x_b_max_tij].mean(axis=0))
            center_y = y_b_min_tij + np.argmax(thresh[y_b_min_tij:y_b_max_tij, x_b_min_tij:x_b_max_tij].mean(axis=1))
    
        elif min_arg == 0:
            
            left_quartile = x_tij < thresh.shape[0] /2 
            upper_quartile = y_tij < thresh.shape[1] /2
    
    
            center_x = x_min_tij + ((x_b_max_tij - x_b_min_tij) / 2)
            center_y = y_min_tij + ((y_b_max_tij - y_b_min_tij) / 2)
    
            
            center_x = x_min_tij + np.argmax(thresh[y_min_tij:y_max_tij, x_min_tij:x_max_tij].mean(axis=0))
            center_y = y_min_tij + np.argmax(thresh[y_min_tij:y_max_tij, x_min_tij:x_max_tij].mean(axis=1))
            
        elif min_arg == 3:
            
            
            left_quartile = x_b_tij_m < thresh.shape[0] /2 
            upper_quartile = y_b_tij_m < thresh.shape[1] /2
    
            center_x = x_b_min_tij_m + ((x_b_max_tij_m - x_b_min_tij_m) / 2)
            center_y = y_b_min_tij_m + (y_b_max_tij_m - y_b_min_tij_m / 2)
            
    
            center_x = x_b_min_tij_m + np.argmax(thresh[y_b_min_tij_m:y_b_max_tij_m, x_b_min_tij_m:x_b_max_tij_m].mean(axis=0))
            center_y = y_b_min_tij_m + np.argmax(thresh[y_b_min_tij_m:y_b_max_tij_m, x_b_min_tij_m:x_b_max_tij_m].mean(axis=1))
    
        else:
            
            left_quartile = x_tij_m < thresh.shape[0] /2 
            upper_quartile = y_tij_m < thresh.shape[1] /2
    
    
            center_x = x_min_tij_m + ((x_b_max_tij_m - x_b_min_tij_m) / 2)
            center_y = y_min_tij_m + ((y_b_max_tij_m - y_b_min_tij_m) / 2)
            
            center_x = x_min_tij_m + np.argmax(thresh[y_min_tij_m:y_max_tij_m, x_min_tij_m:x_max_tij_m].mean(axis=0))
            center_y = y_min_tij_m + np.argmax(thresh[y_min_tij_m:y_max_tij_m, x_min_tij_m:x_max_tij_m].mean(axis=1))
            
        # draw ellipse on copy of input
        result = img.copy() 
        cv2.ellipse(result, ellipse, (0,0,255), 1)

        cv2.line(result, (int(xtop),int(ytop)), (int(xbot),int(ybot)), (255, 0, 0), 1)
        cv2.circle(result, (int(xc),int(yc)), 10, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    
        cv2.circle(result, (int(center_x),int(center_y)), 10, (255, 0, 255), 5)
    
        cv2.circle(result, (int(thresh.shape[1] / 2),int(thresh.shape[0] - 1)), 10, (255, 0, 0), 5)
    
        cv2.rectangle(result,(x_min_tij,y_min_tij),(x_max_tij,y_max_tij),(255,0,0),3)
        cv2.rectangle(result,(x_b_min_tij,y_b_min_tij),(x_b_max_tij,y_b_max_tij),(255,255,0),3)
        
        cv2.rectangle(result,(x_min_tij_m,y_min_tij_m),(x_max_tij_m,y_max_tij_m),(255,0,0),3)
        cv2.rectangle(result,(x_b_min_tij_m,y_b_min_tij_m),(x_b_max_tij_m,y_b_max_tij_m),(255,255,0),3)
        
       
        plt.imshow(result)
        plt.figure()
        #rotate the image    
        rot_img = Image.fromarray(thresh)
            
        #180
        bot_point_x = int(thresh.shape[1] / 2)
        bot_point_y = int(thresh.shape[0] - 1)
        
        #poi
        poi_x = int(center_x)
        poi_y = int(center_y)
        
        #image_center
        im_center_x = int(thresh.shape[1] / 2)
        im_center_y = int(thresh.shape[0] - 1) / 2
        
        #a - adalt, b - abaix, c - dreta
        #ba = a - b
        #bc = c - a(b en realitat) 
        
        ba = np.array([im_center_x, im_center_y]) - np.array([bot_point_x, bot_point_y])
        bc = np.array([poi_x, poi_y]) - np.array([im_center_x, im_center_y])
        
        #angle 3 punts    
        cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
        cos_angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)
        
        cos_angle = np.degrees(cos_angle)
        
        print('cos angle: ', cos_angle)
        
        print('print: ', abs(poi_x- bot_point_x))
        
        m = (int(thresh.shape[1] / 2)-int(center_x) / int(thresh.shape[0] - 1)-int(center_y))
        
        ttan = math.tan(m)
        
        theta = math.atan(ttan)
            
        print('theta: ', theta) 
        
        result = Image.fromarray(result)
        
        result = result.rotate(cos_angle)
        
        plt.imshow(result)
        plt.figure()
    
        #rot_img = rot_img.rotate(origi_angle)
    
        rot_img = rot_img.rotate(cos_angle)
    
        return rot_img
    
    
    rot_img = get_thresholded_rotated(im_path)
    
    plt.imshow(rot_img)
```

Thanks in advance
**--- EDIT ---**

I leave here some raw images as requested.
[image: sample]

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyVV4.jpg)

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

[image: sample]

Comment: This is an interesting problem, and I wish I had time to work on it.  So, let's say you make a bounding ellipse, or even a bounding circle.  Say you divide that circle in two (in lots of different rotations).  For some rotations, the pixel intensity in one half will be WAY higher than the intensity in the other half.  If you find a division that maximizes the ratio between the two halves, then the lower intensity half is the stem part.  See what I mean?

Comment: You probably don't even need a bounding circle.  For each degree from 0 to 359, take a line through the center of the image, and add up the pixels on each side of the line.  That would be easy.  OK, not "easy", but doable.  It's just math, right?  ;)

Comment: One comment. I think you should be thresholding on green using inRange rather than adaptive thresholding. Some of your thresholded images has extraneous parts included.

Comment: You could divide the image into halves first horizontally and then again vertically and check the amount of green. The one with the smallest number of green pixels likely contains your stem.

Comment: fmw42, I could use green threshold with inRange, and may be I will, but I expect the incoming images (this is meant to classify images posted by users to a server) to have any sort of background and not a blank paper, this is why I'm using adaptive threshold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Concept

This works for most of the leaves, as long as they have a stem. So here is the concept for detecting the rotation of and rotating one leaf image:

1. Find the approximated contour of the leaf. As the tip point of the stem will most often belong to the convex hull *(the outer points)* of the leaf, find the convex hull of the contour.
2. Loop through the indices of the contour that belong to the convex hull of the leaf. For each index, calculate the angle between 3 points: the point in the contours before the index, the point in the contours at the index and the point in the contours after the index.
3. The smallest angle calculated would be the tip of the stem. Every time the loop finds a smaller angle, store the three points in a tuple, and when the smallest angle gets detected, calculate the angle of which the stem is pointing at using the center of the 2 coordinates on both sides of the tip of the stem, and the tip of the stem.
4. With the angle of the stem detected we can rotate the image accordingly.

#### The Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3, 3), 2)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 127, 47)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=2)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)
    return img_erode

def get_contours(img):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    return cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.01 * peri, True)

def get_angle(a, b, c):
    ba, bc = a - b, c - b
    cos_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    return np.degrees(np.arccos(cos_angle))
    
def get_rot_angle(img):
    contours = get_contours(img)
    length = len(contours)
    min_angle = 180
    for i in cv2.convexHull(contours, returnPoints=False).ravel():
        a, b, c = contours[[i - 1, i, (i + 1) % length], 0]
        angle = get_angle(a, b, c)
        if angle < min_angle:
            min_angle = angle
            pts = a, b, c
    a, b, c = pts
    return 180 - np.degrees(np.arctan2(*(np.mean((a, c), 0) - b)))

def rotate(img):
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w / 2, h / 2), get_rot_angle(img), 1)
    return cv2.warpAffine(img, rot_mat, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

img = cv2.imread("leaf.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Image", rotate(img))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

#### The Output

Output for every sample image you provided:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### The Explanation

Breaking down the code:

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Define a function, `process`, to process an image into a binary image that will allow the program to accurately detect the contours of the leaves:

```
def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3, 3), 2)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 127, 47)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=2)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)
    return img_erode
```

3. Define a function, `get_contours`, to get the approximate contours of the largest contour in the image, using the `process` function defined before:

```
def get_contours(img):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    return cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.01 * peri, True)
```

3. Define a function, `get_angle`, to get the angle between 3 points:

```
def get_angle(a, b, c):
    ba, bc = a - b, c - b
    cos_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    return np.degrees(np.arccos(cos_angle))
```

4. Define a function, `get_rot_angle`, to get the amount of degrees the image needs to be rotated. It determines this angle by finding the point of the convex hull of the leaf where the angle between the point and the 2 surrounding points in the contour of the leaf where the angle between the 3 points is minimal, using the `get_angle` function defined before:

```
def get_rot_angle(img):
    contours = get_contours(img)
    length = len(contours)
    min_angle = 180
    for i in cv2.convexHull(contours, returnPoints=False).ravel():
        a, b, c = contours[[i - 1, i, (i + 1) % length], 0]
        angle = get_angle(a, b, c)
        if angle < min_angle:
            min_angle = angle
            pts = a, b, c
    a, b, c = pts
    return 180 - np.degrees(np.arctan2(*(np.mean((a, c), 0) - b)))
```

5. Define a function, `rotate`, to rotate the image along its center, using the `get_rot_angle` function defined before:

```
def rotate(img):
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w / 2, h / 2), get_rot_angle(img), 1)
    return cv2.warpAffine(img, rot_mat, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

6. Finally, read in your images, apply the `rotate` function defined before and show the rotated image:

```
img = cv2.imread("leaf.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Image", rotate(img))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this approach solved the problem in most cases (as you pointed out), and thanks for the great explanation as well.

Answer (score 4):

[Bilateral Symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_biology)

Rotate the image. Find the largest contour. Using moments, find the center of that contour. Split the image into left and right parts (Note: applying `cv2.blur(img, 5,5))` produces better results):

[image: rotated leaf]

Flip the right side. Overlay the left and right parts:

[image: overlay]

Use cv2.absDiff() to measure the differences between left and (flipped) right. Because leaves have bilateral symmetry, the difference will be the smallest when the stem (or spine) of the leaf is vertical.

Note: there are going to be two minima; once when the stem is up and once when the stem is down...

[image: plot]

Comment: Haha, I read your answer, saw the animation, and was thinking: "That's him*!" Then, I scrolled down, and - it's you! :D Missed your animations! (*Assuming the pronoun from the first name here.)

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your answer. I was just trying to implement it. When I find the center of mass (moment) this is obviously not the center of the image so left and right are of different size which is a problem for overlaying images.

Comment: @M.Villanueva I ran into that problem too! My solution was to use temporary images that were the same size and then blend them with cv2.addWeighted(). The code wasn't pretty...but it worked. All the relevant pixels are on the right side of the image, so I cropped out the left side of the images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I mean, and this needs to be refined.  This draws an imaginary line through the image center every 5 pixels along the top edge, and then every 5 pixels along the left edge, adds up the pixel values on both sides of the line, and prints the min and max ratios.  The fourth value of the tuple should be the angle of rotation.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import math
from pprint import pprint

def rads(degs):
    return degs * math.pi / 180.0

clr = Image.open('20210210_155311.jpg').resize((640,480)).convert('L')
data = np.asarray(clr)


def ratio_lr( data, left, right ):
    x0 = left
    dx = (right-left) / data.shape[0]

    lsum = 0
    rsum = 0
    for row in range(data.shape[0]):
        lsum += data[row,:int(x0)].sum()
        rsum += data[row,int(x0):].sum()
        x0 += dx

    return lsum / rsum

def ratio_tb( data, top, bottom ):
    y0 = top
    dy = (bottom - top) / data.shape[1]

    tsum = 0
    bsum = 0
    for col in range(data.shape[1]):
        tsum += data[:int(y0),col].sum()
        bsum += data[int(y0):,col].sum()
        y0 += dy

    return tsum / bsum


midx = data.shape[1] // 2
midy = data.shape[0] // 2
track = []
for dx in range(-midx, midx, 5 ):
    if dx == 0:
        angle = 90
    else:
        angle = math.atan( midy / dx  ) * 180 / math.pi
    track.append( (ratio_lr( data, midx+dx, midx-dx ), dx, 0, angle) )

for dy in range(-midy, midy, 5 ):
    angle = math.atan( dy / midx ) * 180 / math.pi
    track.append((ratio_tb( data, midy+dy, midy-dy ), 0, dy, angle))

pprint(track)
print(min(track))
print(max(track))
```